# adding and saving new items to the collection

Tags: windows-phone-7

Assume we have an `Customer` object with collection of `Payments`.

Initialization:

```
var dataContext = new TestDataContext();
dataContext.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(new Customer { Id = 1, Name = "Customer1" });
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
var customer = dataContext.Customers.Where(c => c.Id == 1).First();
```

First case:

```
customer.Payments.Add(new Payment { Amount = 100, CustomerId = customer.Id });
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
var count = dataContext.Payments.Count(); // count == 0
```

Second case:

```
dataContext.Payments.InsertOnSubmit(new Payment { Amount = 100, Customer = customer });
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
var count = dataContext.Payments.Count(); // count == 1
```

Third case (combined):

```
customer.Payments.Add(new Payment { Amount = 100, CustomerId = customer.Id });
dataContext.Payments.InsertOnSubmit(new Payment { Amount = 100, Customer = customer });
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
var count = dataContext.Payments.Count(); // count == 2 (!)
```

I assume that `InsertOnSubmit` somehow notifies the `DataContext` object about changes. But just wondered why it's not notified in the first case?

*P.S. I am using SQL CE for Windows Phone.*

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried setting the customer reference to Payment.Customer property in the first case?

E.g. `customer.Payments.Add(new Payment { Amount = 100, Customer = customer });`

I normally wouldn't set IDs explicitly, but make use of the ORM and establish proper relationships between entities.